Prove $\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi = \int_\Omega F(\nabla u) \varphi$ for weak solution $u$ of PDE $-\Delta u = F(\nabla u)$

Given $u \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ the weak solution of $-\Delta u = F(\nabla u)$ where $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|F(v)| \le |v|^2$.
Prove that, for all $\varphi \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$, we have
$$\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi = \int_\Omega F(\nabla u) \varphi.$$

Things I've done so far:
Let $\{\varphi_k\} \subset C_c^\infty(\Omega) \to \varphi$ in $W^{1,2}$ norm by the definition of $W_0^{1,2}$, then we have
$$\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi_k = -\int_\Omega \Delta u \,\varphi_k = \int_\Omega F(\nabla u) \varphi_k$$
as $u \in W^{1,2}$.
We want to let $k \to \infty$ to obtain the result.
LHS is easy to be controlled by Holder's inequality,
$$\left| \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi_k - \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi \right| \le \int_\Omega |\nabla u| |\nabla \varphi_k - \nabla \varphi| \le \Big(||\nabla u||_{L^2} \, ||\varphi_k - \varphi||_{L^2}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}} \to 0.$$
But similar approach makes no sense to RHS,
$$\left| \int_\Omega F(\nabla u)\varphi_k - \int_\Omega F(\nabla u)\varphi \right| \le \int_\Omega |F(\nabla u)||\varphi_k - \varphi| \le \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 |\varphi_k - \varphi|,$$
then we could do nothing.
There are two roughly sketched ways may work:

Prove or reselect $\varphi_k$ converging to $\varphi$ uniformly, i.e. in $L^\infty$. Then we can simply use ($1, \infty$)-Holder inequality.

Now we have $\varphi_k \to \varphi$ only in $L^2$, or, by further selecting a subsequence, also a.e.
I think 'prove' it may somewhat be nonsense, but 'reselect' it, for example, by convolution, may work.


Divide $\Omega$ into two parts, one bounded. I.e, let $\Omega_1 = \Omega \cap B(0, R)$ where $R$ sufficiently large, and $\Omega_2 = \Omega \backslash \Omega_1$.

In $\Omega_1$, utilize Egroff's theorem to get uniform convergence (aside from a sufficiently small set, denoted as $\Omega_3$). In $\Omega_1\backslash\Omega_3$ we're done.
In $\Omega_2 \cup \Omega_3$ (its measure $\mu(\cdot)<\varepsilon$), as $\nabla u \in L^2$ is absolutely integrable, if $|\varphi_k - \varphi|$ is uniformly bounded, then we're also done. But this seems hard to prove (or even wrong!). (For each $k$, respectively, $|\varphi_k - \varphi|$ is bounded, clearly.)



In summary, the first approach needs uniform convergence, the second needs uniform boundedness, weaker than the first one.
One can easily observe that we haven't utilize that $u \in W_0^{1,2}$ (not just $W^{1,2}$) and that $\varphi \in L^\infty$ bounded, but how? Any comments or solutions will be fully appreciated!

What is your definition of weak solution? The claim looks to me like the standard definition of weak solution...

You don't have to show the weak solution from scratch. Given how the problem statement is, I think you might only need to show $\int_\Omega F(\nabla u) \varphi$ is a bounded linear functional of $\varphi$, which is not hard to solve as you require $ \varphi$ is in $L^\infty$.

@daw In my textbook the test function needs to be $C_c^\infty$ i.e. smooth and with a compact support.

@ShuhaoCao Could you explain it into more detail? I'm fresh in functional analysis but the course somehow decide to introduce Sobolev space first. :(

this is the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4973889/a-property-of-weak-solution
