A property of Weak Solution
$u\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is the weak solution to function $-\Delta u=F(\nabla u)$, where $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is a map satisfying $|F(v)|\le |v|^2$.
Prove: For each $\phi\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)\cap L^\infty (\Omega)$, we have
$$\int_\Omega \nabla u\nabla\phi=\int_\Omega F(\nabla u)\phi.$$
I tried to find a sequence of functions $\{\phi_m\}$ in $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ to approximate $\phi$. The left hand side of the equation can be easily approximated by the one of $\phi_m$, but I had trouble in doing the same thing to the right hand side.

$\textbf{Weak solution}.$ $u\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is a weak solution of $-\Delta u= F(\nabla u)$ implies that for any $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, there holds
$$
  \int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla\phi = \int_{\Omega}F(\nabla u)\phi,
$$
and $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ in the sense of trace.
For any $\phi\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, there exists an approximated sequence $\{\phi_n\}\subset C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ satisfying
$$
  \|\phi_n-\phi\|_{W_0^{1,2}}+\|\phi_n-\phi\|_{L^{\infty}}\to 0,\quad as\ \ n\to\infty.
$$
Set $L[\phi]=\int_{\Omega}(\nabla u\cdot \nabla\phi-F(\nabla u)\phi)$, then
$$\begin{aligned}
  |L[\phi]|\le& |L[\phi-\phi_n]|+|L[\phi_n]| = |L[\phi-\phi_n]|\\
  \le&\int_{\Omega}\bigg|\nabla u\cdot \nabla(\phi-\phi_n)\bigg|+\bigg|F(\nabla u)\cdot(\phi-\phi_n)\bigg|dx\\
  \le& \|u\|_{W_0^{1,2}}\cdot\|\phi-\phi_n\|_{W_0^{1,2}}+\|\phi-\phi_n\|_{L^{\infty}}\cdot\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}\\
  \le&\ C\|u\|_{W_0^{1,2}}\cdot(\|\phi-\phi_n\|_{W_0^{1,2}}+\|\phi-\phi_n\|_{L^{\infty}})\to 0\quad as\ \ n\to\infty.
\end{aligned}$$
Hence, $L[\phi]=0$ for any $\phi\in W_0^{1,2}\cap L^{\infty}$.

Your claim concerning the existence of $\phi_n$ is not true. In fact, if the continuous functions $\phi_n$ would converge uniformly to $\phi$, then $\phi$ would be continuous. However $W_0^{1,2} \cap L^\infty$ contains discontinuous functions.

@gerw Yes, you are right. The proof is based on $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)=\overline{C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)}$ where the closure is based on the norm $|\cdot|{W_0^{1,2}}+|\cdot|{L^{\infty}}$.

Thanks for your solution. However, I still have trouble understanding the existence of such ${\phi_n}$. How could we claim the convergence of  $|\phi_n-\phi|_{L^\infty}$? Could you please give a further explanation? Thanks a lot.
